# Is pipe in linux asynchronous or not?

Tags: linux, redirect, process, pipe

I thought that when i running below commands

```
sleep 10 | sleep 2 | sleep 5
```

Linux process will be

```
86014 ttys002    0:00.03 bash
86146 ttys002    0:00.00 sleep 10
```

when `sleep 10` is end -> `sleep 2` (when sleep 2 is end)-> `sleep 5`
that's i thought
But in Linux bash `sleep 10, sleep 2, sleep 5` are in `ps` same time

Standard output of `sleep 10` process will be redirected to `sleep 5`'s process
But, in that case, `sleep 5`'s process will be finished before `sleep 10`

I'm confused, any google keywords or concepts of that phenomenon?

(I'm not good at English, maybe it's hard to understand this text. Thank you)

Comment: I don't see your source of confusion: `sleep` does not write to stdout nor read from stdin, so the pipes are not used. If no synchronization is needed, every command in the "command pipe" will be run in parallel. What would you expect to happen differently?

Comment: @rodrigo then, when `command 1 | command 2` there's no case that command2 finishes before command 1 finish? i expected that `pipe connect` -> `fork` -> `run command1` -> `command1 finished` -> `wait(command1's process) is end` -> `fork(for command2)` -> `run command2` -> `finish` this process

Comment: I was rereading your question and guessing exactly that. My attempt at an answer below...

Comment: In the generic `cmd1 | cmd2`, the second command will usually block on a read from the pipe.  It will not complete until it reads all the data that it needs.  If it doesn't need any more data, it might as well finish early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you expect the commands to be run in sequence. But that is not what a pipe does.

To run two commands in sequence you use the `;`, what it is called a *command list*, I think:

```
$ time ( sleep 1 ; sleep 2 )
real    0m3.004s
```

You can also do command lists with `&&` (or `||`) so that the sequence is interrupted if one command returns failure (or success).

But when you run two commands with `|` both are run in parallel, and the `stdout` of the first is connected to the `stdin`of the second. That way, the pipe acts as a synchronization object:

- If the second command is faster and empties the pipe, when it reads it will wait for more data
- If the first command is faster and writes too much data to the pipe, its buffer will fill up and it will block until some data is read.
- Additionally, if the second command dies, as soon as the first one writes to `stdout` it will get a `SIGPIPE`, and possibly die.

(Note what would happen if your programs were not run concurrently: your first program could write megabytes of text to `stdout`, and with nobody to read it, the pipe would overflow!)

But since `sleep` does not read or write to the console, when you do `sleep 1 | sleep 2` nothing special happens and both are run concurrently.

The same happens with 3 or any other number of commands in your pipe.

The net effect is that the full sleep is the longest:

```
$ time ( sleep 1 | sleep 2 | sleep 3 | sleep 4 )
real    0m4.004s
```

Comment: "your first program could write megabytes of text to the console".  No. The first program could write data into the pipe, but it isn't writing anything "to the console".  Do not conflate stdout with the tty.

Comment: These two things seem to be conflicting:

1. If the first command is faster and writes too much data to the pipe, its buffer will fill up and it will block until some data is read.

2. your first program could write megabytes of text to stdout, and with nobody to read it, the pipe would overflow!

If thing 1 is true, then the pipe would never overflow, so thing 2 would never happen. Instead, command 1 would block - forever if pipe buffer is never emptied/reduced. 

Can someone pls explain/clarify this in layman terms?

Comment: @q3769: Well, yes, they are conflicting, I'm not a native English speaker, so my wording may not be too clear. What I was trying to say is that the OS behaves as thing 1, because if it were to behave differently bad things could happen, as for example those in thing 2.  That is, the thing 1 is how a pipe works, while thing 2 is how a pipe does not work.

Comment: thx @rodrigo! No, actually it was my English that didn't read correctly. You were clear, and thx for the further clarification; it helps.